# How to get a parameter from Wikipedia infobox?

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia

I would like to get infobox section from Wikipedia. I tried to use the Wikipedia API but the response is very complex:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&titles=Cristiano_Ronaldo&format=json
```

I need for example to extract only `date of birth` parameter. Is it possible?

Comment: The response is just a JSON that you have to process. Could you please post the code for your best attempt? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, you need **date of birth** for [Cristiano Ronaldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristiano_Ronaldo), but this Wikipedia article is associated with Wikidata Item [Q11571](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q11571). This item usually include the most of Wikipedia Infobox parameters (as Property:P569 - [date of birth](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P569)).

So, for your case it is better idea to use [Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities):

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwiki&props=claims&titles=Cristiano_Ronaldo
```

The response include the **date of birth** under property **P569**, and a lot of other information as place of birth, image, sex, official website, country, etc:

```
...
"P569": [{
    "mainsnak": {
        "datavalue": {
            "value": {
                "time": "+1985-02-05T00:00:00Z",
...
```